# create clickable pointlike structure in wpf 3D

Tags: wpf, vb.net, 3d

I have a point3D coordinate and i would like to show it in a viewport. Does anyone know how to model a small ball that has this point3D as the centerpoint and a radius of 2px?

IN SHORT: How do i create a 3D point in wpf that is clickable (so no references to helixtoolkit please)

Thanks

Comment: As pixels are measurement units of the screen, in 3D space, it is not valid! There is no such thing as "radius of (n)px" in 3d...

Comment: @ppeterka, what is 3D space measured in?

Comment: jeah i did not really mean a radius of certain pixels. Just with a value as radius lets say 1 in the coordinate system of the viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. 
Made a class the inherits from the modelvisual3D and used the meshbuilder of the helixtoolkit to create a sphere with a certain diameter. 
Then added this mesh to the content element of my class(that inherits the modelvisual3D).

For the clickable part I used a hittest on my viewport.
I would have liked to use a **modeluielement3D** but you cannot inherit from it. Anyone have any ideas on this part?

@Moderators: Topic can be closed